# managing radiobuttons depending the group (map on map)

Tags: reactjs, forms, prisma

The problem is that when I choose a option here:
[image]
it only selects 1 of the 4. and Gluten? and Size are different modifier groups.

```
  {modifierGroups.map((modifierGroup, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={modifierGroup.id} className="bg-red-200">
      <label> {modifierGroup.name}</label>
        {modifierGroup.modifiers.map((modifier, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={modifier.id} >
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="modifierSelected"
                id={index}
                onChange={()=> setRadioButton(modifier.id)}
                value={radioButton}
                checked={radioButton === modifier.id}
              />
              <label htmlFor={index}>{modifier.type}</label>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: Share your actual code instead of its image!